# change app name and icon for the new version

Tags: ios

Now I have a valid app selling on iTunes store and I'm trying to create a new version, but I want to change the name of the app as well as the icon. I found the place where you could change them, but I wonder if Apple will reject it or not. Has anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can change anything except the bundle ID without problems. Be sure to change the icon for the update rather than for the app that is already on the store. This was the icon on the app store will only be updated once the new version is ready for sale.